# LINQ Subquery issue

Tags: linq

Following is my linq query:

```
var varResourceStatusReportDataBase = 
     (
       from content in listContent
       join workflowInstance in listWorkflkowInstance 
         on content.Field<string>("ows_ID").Trim() 
           equals workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Content ID").Split(';')[0].Trim()
       join WorkflowInstanceStep in listWorkflowInstanceStep 
         on workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_ID") 
           equals WorkflowInstanceStep.Field<string>("ows_Workflow Instance ID").Split(';')[0]
       select new
       {
         ContentName = content.Field<string>("ows_Name"),
         WorkflowInstanceId = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_ID"),
         WIName = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Title"),
         WIPlannedStartDate = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Planned Start Date") ?? "",
         WIPlannedEndDate = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Planned End Date") ?? "",
         WIActualStartDate = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Actual Start Date") ?? "",
         WIActualEndDate = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Actual End Date") ?? "",
         WIApprovalDate = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Approval Date") ?? "",
         WITaskStatus = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Status").ToUpper() ?? "",
         WIMetadataStatus = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Metadata Status") ?? "",
         WIApprover = workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_Approver").Replace("#", "").Split(';')[1].ToUpper() ?? "",
         WISResponsible = WorkflowInstanceStep.Field<string>("ows_Responsible").Replace("#", "").Split(';')[1].ToUpper() ?? "",
         WISDesiredEndDate= 
           (
             from WorkflowInstanceStep1 in listWorkflowInstanceStep 
             where (WorkflowInstanceStep1.Field<string>("ows_Status") =="IN PROGRESS" ||
                    WorkflowInstanceStep1.Field<string>("ows_Status") =="ASSIGNED") && 
                    workflowInstance.Field<string>("ows_ID") == WorkflowInstanceStep1.Field<string>("ows_Workflow Instance ID").Split(';')[0]
             select new {abc = WorkflowInstanceStep1.Field<string>("ows_Desired End Date")}).Take(1)
        }).Distinct();
```

I have sub-query in above query to calculate `WISDesiredEndDate`, but when I execute this query, I get `System.Linq.Enumerable+TakeIterator>d__3a'1[<>f__AnonymousType1'1[System.String]]` value for `WISDesiredEndDate` column not actual value which I want.
Please give suggestion on the same. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `FirstOrDefault()` rather than `Take(1)`

As from comments, you don't want a anonymous object so change the select to be

```
select  WorkflowInstanceStep1.Field<string>("ows_Desired End Date")}).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It worked for me but now "WISDesiredEndDate" column is giving value { abc = 2014-02-28 00:00:00 } but I want only date.

Answer (score 0):

You can us [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) more readable code. Nevertheless you have to force linq expression execution by calling FirstOrDefault method

```
let desiredEndDate = (from WorkflowInstanceStep1 in listWorkflowInstanceStep .... Take(1))
select new
{
...
     WISDesiredEndDate= desiredEndDate.FirstOrDefault()
}
```